# Page keeps loading, Google Calendar API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-calendar-api

I have created an ASP.Net Core MVC project and integrated the Google Calendar API:
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 with a NuGet package

[I followed this guide](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet?authuser=1).

it seems to work since i see some records from my calendar in the output window of my visual studio
but the page themself never stops loading?

i removed the default pages and events in the HomeController only Index is left
and replaced the code from the program.cs with the code from google.

```
namespace CalendarQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
        // at ~/.credentials/calendar-dotnet-quickstart.json
        static string[] Scopes = { CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly };
        static string ApplicationName = "Google Calendar API .NET Quickstart";`

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserCredential credential;

            using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }

            // Create Google Calendar API service.
            var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });

            // Define parameters of request.
            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

            // List events.
            Events events = request.Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Upcoming events:");
            if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
                {
                    string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                    {
                        when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", eventItem.Summary, when);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No upcoming events found.");
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

so I can't see my index view.

Comment: i just removed the default pages like About , etc and the events in the HomeController and replaced the Program.cs code wit hthe one from the google website

Answer (score 0):

replacing the List Events with : 
`CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();`

and adding :

`public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();`

i am able to see the Index Page/View again